# Reading two dimensional array from file and printing it

Tags: c, arrays, linux, gcc

I have some problems with my code. Everything is fine; gcc shows no errors or warnings; valgrind says no memory leaks, but my array isn't printed and I'm not sure why. Is `fscanf()` not working correctly or am I printing it incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arrsize (FILE *file)
{
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: file pointer is null.");
        return 0;
    }
    int sizer;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &size);
    return size;
}


int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0,a=0;

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("matrix.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: file pointer is null.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int size = arrsize(fp);

    printf("Array size is %d x %d \n", size, size);

    double **array = (double **)malloc(size * sizeof(double *));
    for (i; i < size; i++)
       array[i] = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    for (i; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, " %lf", &array[i][j]); 
            printf(" %lf ",array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (k ; k < size; k++) {
        free(array[k]);        
    }
    free(array);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int sizer;` --> `int size;`

Comment: `for (i; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)` --> `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)`

Comment: You've not shown a small example of the data file that you're reading, nor your actual or expected outputs.  Those are an important part of an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: You should probably add a newline after  you print each row of the matrix.  It is also a more acid test to read the entire matrix and then print the entire matrix as two separate sets of loops.  Many a program has gone wrong because although the value printed immediately after it was read, the value was no longer correct when the input was complete.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I agree that the change in the loops is desirable.  However, it isn't strictly necessary since `int i = 0, …` does initialize `i` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return of `fscanf` and `malloc` to make sure of success.
Add `fflush ( stdout);` to the print loops since the format string does not have a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arrsize (FILE *file)
{
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: file pointer is null.");
        return 0;
    }
    int size;
    if ( 1 == fscanf(file, "%d", &size)) {
        return size;
    }
    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("matrix.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: file pointer is null.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int size = arrsize(fp);
    if ( -1 == size) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error: problem parsing array size.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Array size is %d x %d \n", size, size);

    double **array = NULL;
    if ( NULL != ( array = malloc(size * sizeof(double *)))) {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if ( NULL == ( array[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(double)))) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem allocation array[]\n");
                while ( i) {
                    i--;
                    free ( array[i]);
                }
                free ( array);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem allocation array\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if ( 1 == fscanf(fp, "%lf", &array[i][j])) {
                printf(" %lf ",array[i][j]);
            }
            else {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem parsing double\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        fflush ( stdout);
    }

    for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        free(array[k]);
    }
    free(array);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```